# Reading from .txt files into an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

So, I'm trying to read data from multiple `.txt` files into a single array, but have not been able to have the program work even with a single file. The input files are in the format, `[int tabspace int tabspace string]`, for example

```
004 78 inmW (tabspace between the entries)

006 89 inmW
```

I want to be able to read the two numbers, each into a separate array, and ignore the string at the end. So far I'm using the following code to do this for the first file, but can't seem to read even the 1st entry correctly. I also haven't been able to find anything on how to handle the undesired string in each entry.

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int HR[50];
    int BPD[50];
    int BPS[50];
    float BT[50];
    int HR_Time[50];
    int BT_Time[50];
    int BP_Time[50];
    char buffer[100];
    char temp[10]; 

    FILE *HRfile;
    HRfile=fopen("HR_1.txt","r");

    if(HRfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open patient info file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fscanf(HRfile,"%d  %d", &HR_Time[i], &HR[i])!=EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }



      fclose(HRfile);

    HRfile=fopen("HR_2.txt","r");
    if(HRfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open patient info file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(fscanf(HRfile,"%d  %d", &HR_Time[i], &HR[i])!=EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }

    fclose(HRfile);

    printf("%d %d", HR[2],HR_Time[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the `printf` statement to make sure the files were read by printing a value of the arrays.

However, my result is simply a blank command prompt, with absolutely nothing in it.

Comment: How would I do this for a multiple line txt file? I thought fgets would only read a single line and not continue after whitespace

Comment: How would you set up the sscanf? I'm trying right now with `while(fgets(temp,sizeof temp,HRfile)!=NULL)` and then inside the loop I have `sscanf(temp,"%d %d %s", &HR[i], &HR_TIme[i], &buffer[i]); i++;` but it doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an array large enough to capture the longest line, `fgets` will read each line up to and including the newline. The while will terminate at the end of the file.
Use `sscanf` to read the two integers from the beginning of the line.
Check that `i` does not exceed the storage for the integer arrays.

```
char line[100] = "";
while(fgets ( line, sizeof line, HRfile))
{
    if ( 2 == sscanf(line,"%d  %d", &HR_Time[i], &HR[i]))
    {
        i++;
        if ( i >= 50) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This finally worked, I was making a mistake in keeping a placeholder for the necessary string earlier! Now I just need to implement this for multiple files in the same code.... :)